# True or false: $\forall x \in \Bbb R,\exists y\in \Bbb R,y+x=x+y$

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

How would one tell if this is true or false.

1: $\forall x \in \Bbb R,\exists y\in \Bbb R,y+x=x+y$

2: $\exists x \in \Bbb R,\forall y \in \Bbb R,y+x=x+y$

---

For the first I think it would be true because if $x=8$ then

$y+8=8+y$

$y=2$

So to justify it would I say true because of commutative property.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Have you tried mimicing the work done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549310/discrete-math-logic-question)?

Comment: Try thinking along the line that $\mathbb{R}$ has zero. not sure if this helps.

Comment: Hmm yes but if I do for any x $y$ must be $y=x-x+y$ so $y=y$

Comment: If you say $y=y$ I guess that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both statements are true, regardless of our choices for $x, y$. $$y + x = x+y$$ is true for any arbitrary pair of real numbers $(x, y)$, and as you note, this is due to the commutativity of addition over the real numbers.

Note: In your first case, if $x = 8$, the statement holds regardless of the value of $y\in \mathbb R$, and not just when $y = 2$.

Comment: Yes it makes sense sometimes the order of the symbol get me confused.

Comment: You've had pretty good intuition today on how order matters, and understanding correctly what is being conveyed.

Comment: Could another justification be that no matter what x you chose in $x+y=y+x$ $y$ must be equal on both sides

Comment: Sure: $x + y = y + x \implies x = x, y = y, 0 = 0$. All true.

Comment: @amWhy: This is one of those examples where I have seen growth from an OP +1

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, every element has an additive inverse which commutes with it. Hence there does exist $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $y+x=x+y$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, namely $y=-x$.

Similarly for the second statement, there must exist an additive identity, namely $x=0$ such that $y+x=x+y$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $y$ can be any number, not just $y = -x$. I am stating that such a $y$ exists, and it need not be that $y = -x$.

Comment: The statement does not require that $y$ can be any number, simply that a $y$ exists.

Comment: I.e., there exists uncountably many $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $y + x = x+y$

Comment: @AustinRannow Sure, but your answer might create the mistaken impression that there is some important reason to consider $y = -x$.

Comment: @AustinRannow Also, your claim that the second statement can be proved similarly is not quite right. The second statement says that there is a (fixed) $x$ that commutes with _every_ $y$, and of course there is no fixed $x$ that is the negative of every $y$.

Comment: I believe it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is now correct.  I suppose the advantage of this argument is that it works for some more general algebraic structures (which the OP probably has not seen.) Actually, one final nitpick: "is commutative" should be "commutes with it" because "commutative" doesn't apply to individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are true, but your example of $2+8 = 8+2$ doesn't prove either, it just shows that the statement

$\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \,\exists y \in \mathbb{R},\,x+y = y+x$

is true; that is, that there exists *some* $x$ and $y$ that commute with one another.  (We say that $x$ and $y$ *commute* if $x+y = y+x$.) On the other hand the original statements

1. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \,\exists y \in \mathbb{R},\,x+y = y+x$
2. $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, \,\forall y \in \mathbb{R},\,x+y = y+x$

say respectively that

1. For every $x$, there is a $y$ that commutes with it, and
2. There is an $x$ such that every $y$ commutes with it.

Unfortunately this is not a very good example to clarify the meaning of $\forall$ versus $\exists$, because in $\mathbb{R}$ we have that *every* $x$ commutes with *every* $y$, so that all of the statements are trivially true.